# Mock a module using qmltestrunner ? Is it possible?

Tags: qt, unit-testing, qml

I am running some QML Unit tests and they being tested using "qmltestrunner" However, I am stuck on something that I am not sure it is possible to mock it.

Here a snipped on my "TitleBusyIndicator.qml":

```
import QtQuick.Layouts
import QtQuick.Controls.Material

import GUI.PageNavigatorPT 1.0

Rectangle
{
    width: parent.width
    height: parent.height
```

... a bunch of stuff

here is part of my unit test that will test the QML above

import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtTest
Rectangle
{
TitleBusyIndicator
{
id : titleBusyIndicatorId
}

However the import below is not known to the QMLTestRunner because it does not have the full project. It just testing one single qml file.

```
import GUI.PageNavigatorPT 1.0
```

When I try to run the unittest I get this (expected):

```
Running test = %QMLTESTRUNNER%\qmltestrunner -input tst_TitleBusyIndicator.qml
********* Start testing of qmltestrunner *********
Config: Using QtTest library 6.3.1, Qt 6.3.1 (x86_64-little_endian-llp64 shared (dynamic) release build; by GCC 11.2.0), windows 10
QWARN  : qmltestrunner::tst_TitleBusyIndicator::compile()
tst_TitleBusyIndicator.qml produced 2 error(s):
tst_TitleBusyIndicator.qml:18,5: Type TitleBusyIndicator unavailable
TitleBusyIndicator.qml:21,1: module "GUI.PageNavigatorPT" is not installed
```

Is there a way to make qmltestrunner ignore the module or mock it? I could not find much documention on how to mock modules inside qml files for qml runner.

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using Qt6.3.1 you should consult https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-syntax-imports.html specifically the section on QML Import Path in particular the section regarding setting the `QML_IMPORT_PATH` environment variable.

In short, you should consider setting `QML_IMPORT_PATH` prior to running `qmltestrunner`. This allows you to nominate additional Qt QML plugins that may not be part of the standard Qt install.

You can use `QML_IMPORT_PATH` to point to production, QA, dev, or even stub versions of your Qt QML Plugin.

If those plugins have additional dependencies, you may need to also append those to the `PATH` environment variable so that the `qmltestrunner` can find those as well.

For completeness, for those who are on older Qt5.15.x or older, the environment variable is `QML2_IMPORT_PATH`. For more details, see https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-imports.html

Comment: thank you. Can I see an example? Is it just a matter to declare the env var and make it point to my qml plugin? I will try.

Comment: On Windows, for example, open a Terminal and type `SET "QML_IMPORT_PATH=C:\Blahblah\MyApp\qml"` then you can invoke `qmltestrunner`. The location needs to be the parent qml directory containing your `GUI.PageNavigatorPT` Qt QML Plugin. For Linux/macOS, you may have to use either the `setenv` or `export` BASH commands. It would help if you add to your question some technical details on the platform you're on (seems to be Windows 10) and how you are launching `qmltestrunner`.